# Python mysql stored procedure callproc() doesnt work

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, pyodbc, mysql-connector

I have a stored procedure on mysql database.When I call this procedure on phpmyadmin

```
CALL bakiyesifirla('Deneme');


CREATE PROCEDURE bakiyesifirla(IN cadres varchar(500)) 
BEGIN 
    set @bakiye=0; 
    CALL bakiyecek(cadres,@bakiye); 
    IF @bakiye<0 THEN 
       CALL bakiyeguncelle(0,cadres); 
    END IF; 
END; –
```

it works fine but when I try to call it on python with

```
  cadres='Deneme'
  mycursor = mydb.cursor()
  mycursor.callproc('bakiyesifirla',[cadres,])
  mycursor.close()
```

it doesnt give any error but it wont make  any difference.

Comment: can you add the porocdure

Comment: Are you sure that you are using pyodbc? When I try to use `.callproc()` I get "AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'callproc'". pyodbc has not implemented `.callproc()` as noted in the wiki [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#callprocprocname-parameters).

Comment: Facing same error! Did you got the solution?

Comment: Add `mydb.commit()` before `mycursor.close()`. this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use a [tuples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html) not arrays

```
mycursor.callproc('bakiyesifirla',(cadres,))
```

But i can't see how you can check, if the procedures are called or not.

Add some out paramters to check,if  also the sub stored procedures are running see the link provided

Comment: it is hard to tell what happens in the other procedures do they run in workbench?

Comment: I check it on if  database value changed to 0

Comment: its working when I execute CALL bakiyesifirla('Deneme'); this sql command on phpmyadmin

Comment: try the sample procedures provided by mysql and see if they yield an answer

Comment: I already try simple procedure it works but somehow that one doesnt work on python other simple procedures works I wonder why is this happening.

Comment: i would look into it, make a dbfillde with all involved tables and procedures

Comment: ```cur.callproc("multiply", (5, 6, 0))``` not working too

Comment: @Prashant for you the same make a dbfiddle with all procedures , so that others can check ideally amke a new question

Answer (score -1):

You have to call 'mydb.commit()' after calling 'cursor.callproc', and before closing the db connection.